# Breezejs new version's merge entities feature

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of Breezejs (from 1.3.6 to 1.4.1).
I have a situation where I fetch entities from the server, and I get something like

```
{
    "$type": "X.Y.Reference, X.Y",
    "ReferenceTypeId": "BookEdited",
    "ShouldDisplay": true,
    "ShortTitle": "Informationsethik 1995",
    "Title": "Informationsethik",
    "Year": "1995",
    "YearResolved": "1995",
    "CloudProjectSubset": "ReferenceNavigation",
    "Id": "34e1f0d1-eda7-4926-a13f-e75e43ff66b5",
    "ProjectId": "syncproject1"
  },
```

I would like you to notice the "ShouldDisplay" property set to true.
Later, due to the logic of my app, I do another query and I get among the others, the same entity, this time like that:

```
{
    "$type": "X.Y.Reference, X.Y",
    "ReferenceTypeId": "BookEdited",
    "ShortTitle": "Informationsethik 1995",
    "Title": "Informationsethik",
    "Year": "1995",
    "YearResolved": "1995",
    "CloudProjectSubset": "ReferenceNavigation",
    "Id": "34e1f0d1-eda7-4926-a13f-e75e43ff66b5",
    "ProjectId": "syncproject1"
  },
```

notice I no longer get the property "ShouldDisplay", which is correct due to my logic.
Breezejs merges the entities to the local cache after every query. The point is, when using version 1.3.6 after the second query I still have my entity with 'ShouldDisplay' set to true (which is what I want) because the second query returns the same entity without that property, which then doesn't get overwritten. Whereas, if I use versio 1.4.1, the property (even if not serialized) is overwritten anyway and set to null, which is not what I would like.
In short, it seems to me that in version 1.3.6 only returned properties were actually overwritten, instead with 1.4.1 all properties are overwritten.
On Breezejs's [website](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/introduction) or in the web I didn't find information about this 'merging' behaviour, only a setting regarding the merging strategies with regard to pending changes, which is not what I'm facing right now. Does anybody know if this is the way Breezejs is supposed to work or am I missing some configuration? Thank you.

Comment: The latest version of breeze is 1.4.9. Is this what you are using?

Comment: Yes it is. I have updated it yesterday. Up to version 1.3.6 it was working fine (in fact the line of code I point out in my answer below did not have the !== undefined check), from 1.4.1 and future releases I had this problem which I have seemed to solve yesterday. Still don't know whether this is a feature or a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after debugging the source code of Breeze I have figured it out. I'll post my solution in case it will be useful for someone or maybe for the Breeze guys if they want to check whether this is a feature or a bug.
I had replaced this line

```
return val !== undefined ? val : dp.defaultValue;
```

with this line

```
return val;
```

inside the methods ctor.getRawValueFromServer and ctor.getRawValueFromClient. The point is: when an entity has to be merged, a method called updateEntity is fired, which loops through the target entity properties and checks whether they are defined in the raw entity that has been gotten from the server. The method then replaces the property on the target entity if the value of that property on the raw entity is not 'undefined'. The problem is that with the original line of code (shown above), if the value is 'undefined', it is returned the default value of the property, which in my case was 'null', so ALL the properties of my entity were replaced. Now it's working fine. I have done this correction on the latest (as of today) version of Breezejs, which is currently 1.4.9.
Hope it helps someone.